# Passing more than 1 variable of different type within an AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have an AsyncTask, and in doInBackground (), I wish to call publishProgress() and pass it more than 1 variable, of different types, say, a String and an Integer. How can I do this? I tried to define onProgressUpdate(Object... values) and then call it via publishProgress(StringVar, IntVar), and then in onProgressUpdate(), I tried to access them via values[0] and values[1] but that didn't work.

How can I achieve this?

Thanks.

Comment: I believe it's possible to use your current method. You just need to cast them back to the original type.

Comment: You mean keep the "Object" type, calling publishProgress(StringVar, IntVar) and then in onProgressUpdate, casting the values[n] back to the original type?

Comment: Thanks, I tried that and it worked!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest way to do this would probably be to define a wrapper class that takes a string and an integer. Then create an async task that uses this wrapper for its progress udpates.

```
public class Wrapper{
    public final String mString;
    public final Integer mInteger;

    public Wrapper(String myString, Integer myInteger){
        mString = myString;
        mInteger = myInteger;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a class to wrap your progress values:

```
class ProgressUpdate {
    public final String detail;
    public final int value;

    public ProgressUpdate(String detail, int value) {
        this.detail = detail;
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

Then, publish your progress:

```
publishProgress(new ProgressUpdate(detail, value));
```